# Can't select dropdown item with enter in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to select dropdown item with ENTER key and for some reason this is not working. 
This is my code:

```
  <button id="time_btn" type="button"
            class="btn btn-reverse dropdown-toggle"
            data-toggle="dropdown">
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li ng-repeat="item in items" ><a><span>{{item.name}}</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You posted "test" instead of the code :)

Comment: What am I doing wrong? `You are not posting the actual code`